# How to generate big prime numbers using the OpenSSL library?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, primes, bignum

I'm trying to implement ElGamal cryptosystem and I decided to use OpenSSL to generate big primes. I've seen several functions that generate big random numbers but I haven't found a function to generate prime numbers. What function should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a function of the underlying Big Number (BN) implementation rather than a specific high level crypto function, so I guess you'd use [`BN_generate_prime_ex`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/BN_generate_prime_ex.html).

Comment: thanks. I missed this function although I thought that I had seen all functions)))

Comment: Sometimes you'd miss functions if you search with minimally different search terms, so yeah, it happens. Would have closed the question if you didn't already indicate that you searched for it.